# Uploading multiple files with same name in the same folder through rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can I upload multiple files with same name in the  same folder in SharePoint through rest api?If yes, then please provide example of the rest call of how it can be done.

Comment: You cannot add file with same name in same folder. you need to replace the old file if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. SharePoint treats the file name as the primary key identifier for a document.

so if you try to upload a second document with the same name, it will overwrite the original file with the new one or return an exception "A file with the name xxx already exists".

If you need two documents with the same name, you will have to either place them in different folders within a document library or in different document libraries.

Thanks
Baker Kong

Comment: Thanks for the  answer.